# How to avoid post-training brain fuzziness

Tags: weightlifting, post-workout, dehydration, brain, tiredness

I know, brain fuzziness isn't a technical term, but hopefully it makes sense...

I train in the mornings before work (because the gym is waaay too busy after work), usually around 0700, after waking up somewhere between 0600 and 0630.

I generally eat a banana and have a glass of beetroot juice before training, just so I've got something in my stomach to train on (note: I never used to do this and used to feel really sick part way through the session, so this does solve one issue).

The training is either Squats > Overhead presses > Chin-ups or Squats > Kettlebell swings > Turkish get-ups.

The workouts are tiring, but I wouldn't say excessively so and I generally leave feeling pretty good, but knowing that I've trained.

Post workout I have a whey protein shake, followed about 30 minutes later by something along the lines of roast butternut squash / sweet potato (or stir-fry veg) and some form of protein, normally fish related.

The problem is, when I get to work (I work as a software developer), my head gets a bit "fuzzy" or "foggy" and I really struggle to concentrate on things for a few hours. If I'm working on something I know well, then it's not an issue, but if I'm working on something unfamiliar, I really struggle to work through things.

Has anyone else come across this? Could it be some form of low level dehydration (I'll admit, I normally forget to drink during the training session, but tend to chug up to a litre of water when I wake up). Any suggestions as to how to avoid it (aside from not training in the mornings).

Comment: Have you checked for underlying medical reasons?

Comment: No, but it only happens post training when I head to work (it could be related to lack of motivation at my current job :)
I seriously doubt it's a medical issue, a recent series of blood tests for other things turned up nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: Have you tried upping your water intake? You are more dehydrated first thing in the morning. Try a pint of water before you go to bed and first thing in the morning as well as drinking during training and see if that helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is anecdotal from personal experience.
You could very well be crashing post workout. Does your "fuzzybrain" go away after you eat and drinking?
Have you considered blood sugar levels post workout, or eating something more then a protein shake post workout.

I would suggest. Throw in some (teaspoon or less) honey in your protein shake, to get glucose levels up quickly after workout, and have oatmeal or some other complex carb source to follow.
Make sure you are drinking plenty of water so you are not dehydrating yourself.
Additional blood pressure, how is your BP post training?

Comment: Would've marked this as the answer sooner, but wanted to test it first :)  I now have a couple of handfulls of blueberries and rasins post workout with my shake, and it works a treat

Comment: Fantastic! Glad it has worked out so easy